# UserLoginInfo - retrieving info from a sealed class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, class, sealed

I am in the process of making an EF/MVC application which utilizes OAuth2/Owin for third party logins in addition to local user creation. Some of these third parties have APIs allowing you to further personalize the experience by retrieving data specific to that user with some data based on their returned ID.

For instance, I've integrated a Steam One-click login, and using the returned 64-bit user ID which is part of the ProviderKey stored after successful authentication, I can then start pulling information about that user and start using/displaying that data to help streamline or otherwise enhance the application.

My question is how I can retrieve this information that is being stored. using the default user authentication functionality. I've located exactly what I'm looking for, which is

```
    UserLoginInfo
    //This is an extension of 
    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
```

It is a sealed class which holds a LoginProvider and Providerkey (the latter is prize I'm seeking). These are stored with a foreign key of sorts representing the User ID.

This may be a terribly amateur question, but how can I obtain information from this UserLoginInfo class?

For reference, here is a quick article on how this is set up: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on ...in the event you're not familiar with what I'm babbling about.

I sincerely appreciate any guidance on this that can be provided. If I've been unclear at all please let me know so I can explain better.

Cheers

Edit 6/4/15: 
Another example, since this is fairly specific and hasn't yielded a single reply, would be the user token for Twitter, Google+, or Facebook, all of which are included in the default Third-party login of the MVC 4.5 EF Authentication platform.

If you use the default connection string when creating the database context, a separate datastore is created which will hold user logins, claims, roles, etc. Specifically, the UserLogins will hold this information, with each user having the ability to have all of their accounts associated to a profile (UserID for *my* website, i.e. there will be an entry for each of these social media sites with a common UserID).

Since the pre-built Authorization libraries used for much of this functionality are sealed, I realize there are some barriers. I'm trying to find an elegant way of retrieving this *one* piece of information for each of my users so that I can have more engaging content, but searching the web I have found *very* little information relating to this subject (which is not terribly surprising considering the age of this code and functionality). Does anyone know of a resource that might aid in tracking down how to make a customized version of the user management that might allow for a more direct control of the user information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you're looking to find, for example, the Facebook ID of the user who is logged in.

You can get all the logins for a user via [`UserManager<>.GetLoginsAsync(string userId)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497557(v=vs.108).aspx). I don't think there's a more optimized way to just fetch a single one, but it's unlikely--impossible, even--any users would have a huge quantity anyway, which means performance shouldn't be an issue.

So in your controller, you could get the Facebook ID with something like this:

```
var logins = await Request.GetOwinContext()
                          .Get<ApplicationUserManager>()
                          .GetLoginsAsync(this.User.Identity.GetUserId());

var facebookId = logins.Where(c => c.LoginProvider == "Facebook")
                       .Select(c => c.ProviderKey)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

I think the string "Facebook" is a constant somewhere in Identity, so you'd probably want to use that, but as I understand your goal, I think this should do it.

If I were you, I'd probably pin a method onto `ApplicationUserManager` to do this for you:

```
public async Task<string> GetLoginProviderKeyOrNullAsync(string UserId, string Provider)
{
    var logins = await this.GetLoginsAsync(UserId);

    return logins.Where(c => c.LoginProvider == Provider)
                 .Select(c => c.ProviderKey)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: This info jumped me leagues ahead of where I was previously at, but as I start picking at this and trying to use it in various forms in my application, I am realizing there is a fundamental gap in knowledge about what is going on regarding OAuth and the inner workings you're describing here. Do you know of any resources that might help get me up to speed in that regard?

Comment: @devKev I don't know a ton about the stuff, myself. I generally just search anytime I have issues--there are tons of blog posts about that out on the net, of course, but I don't have any recommendations. If you have any specific questions, I'd gladly do what I could to help.